# How to use variable in "having" clause without selecting it?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this large query here:

```
select
 user_contact_id as userContactId,
 max(attempt_number) as attemptNumber,
 max(sent_timestamp) as sentTimestamp,
 source as source,
 from
    share_email_tracking `set`
 group by
    user_contact_id
 having
     (attemptNumber = 1 and date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 4 day) >= date(sentTimestamp))
```

Problem is, I'm not actually interested in `attemptNumber` or `sentTimestamp`.  I just need those to compute the "having" clause.  I'm not aware of any syntax that does this, and I think this is a more general problem than "having" so I haven't been able to find it in documentation on it. I believe temp variables are possible but to my knowledge these are session-specific, not query-specific, and I don't want them polluting the state. Is this possible?

In real life I'm duplicating the `sentTimestamp` several times so I should avoid just substituting it into the having raw.

Answer (score 3):

You could just put them in your `Having`.  Just use the actual expression and not the alias.

```
select  user_contact_id as userContactId,
        source as source

from    share_email_tracking `set`

group by user_contact_id

having (max(attempt_number) = 1 and date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 4 day) >= max(sent_timestamp))
```

You could do this if you want to alias expressions so that you don't have to write them multiple times in your having clause.  Create a sub-select and then use the aliases in the `WHERE` clause of your main query.

```
select  userContactId, source

FROM

(

 select  user_contact_id as userContactId,
         max(attempt_number) as attemptNumber,
         max(sent_timestamp) as sentTimestamp,
         source as source

 from    share_email_tracking `set`

 group by user_contact_id

) as x

WHERE    (attemptNumber = 1 and date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 4 day) >= date(sentTimestamp))
```

Comment: Works, but then I'll be duplicating `max(sent_timestamp)` several times in my real life having clause.

Answer (score 0):

you could do them in where clause

```
   select
 user_contact_id as userContactId,
 max(attempt_number) as attemptNumber,
 max(sent_timestamp) as sentTimestamp,
 source as source,
from
   share_email_tracking `set`

group by
user_contact_id
HAVING  max(attempt_number) = 1  AND date(sentTimestamp) <= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 4 day)
```

Comment: No, that's a syntax error. Those data don't exist until the group by is finished, which has to happen after the where is computed.

Comment: Works, but then I'll be duplicating `max(sent_timestamp)` several times in my real life having clause.